# Change Visual Studio 2012 C# Modulus Format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

How do you change Visual Studio's options for formatting the modulus (%) operator?

For example, whenever I type the line

```
int x = a % b;
```

Visual Studio changes it to

```
int x = a%b;
```

when I type the semi-colon. I would prefer that it automatically add spaces around the modulus operator instead of take them away.

Comment: Bizarre "defaults" in your VS2k12 install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out Resharper was the culprit. Went to Resharper >> Options... >> Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Spaces >> Around Operators >> Multiplicative operators.

Answer (score 9):

tools -> options -> text editor -> c# -> formatting -> spacing:

[image]

Comment: This option is ignored if Resharper is installed. See MageWind's answer.